# Local Admin Login While Someone Is Already Logged In

Tags: login, administrator

In my current job I am an admin working with Macs in a school district.  I previously worked in a district that had an interesting option for local tech accounts to bypass the logged in user by pressing opt + cmd + enter.  This presented a blank login name and password, you put in the tech account, and then you were on the desktop of the logged in user.  This was helpful for some troubleshooting we did, or when we wanted to login and properly log a student out of a computer, making sure to save their work if they left the computer and went to another class.

I am wondering how that was setup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how they did it, but you can switch user account easily enough.

Go to the Lock Screen (Apple menu or Command CTRL Q), and there's a button that says "Switch Users". You'll then be able to enter another username and password.

The original user will still be logged in, and you can switch back when finished. If you want to Log out of the original account, then again, that's the in the Apple menu, and once that's completed, there's a login screen for any user.

(Logging out may take a while, waiting for apps to close, and dealing with unsaved documents.)

Comment: We have that disabled, so no we can't switch users.

Comment: @JohnWhiteaker You've disabled switching users? Or the Lock Screen?